# What is the meaning of Non-Relativistic theory in Condensed Matter Physics?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, condensed-matter, superconductivity

I an attempt to evade the Goldstone Theorem, it is argued in Gilbert and Klein and Lee's paper that in a non-relativistic field there exists a preferred direction which can be used to evade Goldstone's Theorem. Such a preferred direction exists in some condensed matter systems like a ferromagnet. There exists an external preferred direction given by the externally applied field.

My question is on the definition on Non-relativistic field theory in Condensed Matter Physics. **Does non-relativistic fields means one which has a preferred direction and hence is not Lorentz invariant?** This definition is not the same as one where the velocity is much smaller than the speed of light, which is the usual definition of non-relativistic limit.

References: http://prl.aps.org/abstract/PRL/v12/i25/p713_1
http://prl.aps.org/abstract/PRL/v12/i10/p266_1

Comment: Preferred direction in *space* or *spacetime*?

Comment: In spacetime. We basically have a unit time like vector $n_\mu$ which specifies the direction.

Answer (score 1):

You should not worried too much about these papers. The way to evade the Goldstone theorem is the Higgs mechanism, which discusses *local* gauge transformation and invariance of the theory. This can be done both in relativistic and non-relativistic formalism (where it is called a Anderson-Higgs mechanism).

More details -- even discussing the paper by Gilbert and the Anderson's contribution, too -- in the [Nobel Commitee document from the 2013 Nobel Prize](http://www.nobelprize.org/nobel_prizes/physics/laureates/2013/advanced.html).

In particular, the two last paragraphs of page 7 discuss the two papers you refer to:

> Anderson’s ideas were not pursued much by particle physicists, who instead tried to even further strengthen Goldstone’s theorem. However in a paper [*reference*] from March 1964, Abraham Klein and Benjamin W. Lee,
>   inspired by the comment of Anderson took up the question if one would be able to sidestep Goldstone’s theorem in a relativistically invariant theory. They set up a non-relativistic version of the arguments by Goldstone, Abdus Salam and Weinberg. They then followed it through and argued that also in this case there should be a massless scalar mode.
>   Finally they
>   showed
>   the flaw in the argument and stated that the
>   same
>   would be valid
>   in a
>   relativistic theory.
>
> Their arguments were immediately criticised by Walter Gilbert (Nobel Prize in chemistry,1980) [*reference*]. He showed that the arguments of Klein and Lee could be given a seemingly relativistic
>   form by introducing
>   a constant vector $n^{\mu}=\left(1,0,0,0\right)$. He could then show how terms can cancel
>   each other leading to the absence of a massless pole. In the relativistic case there is only one
>   vector at hand, the momentum, $k^{\mu}$, and the cancellation cannot occur. This was the situation up
>   to the summer of 1964 when the breakthrough finally came.

Then the next section discusses the appearance of the Higgs and Englert & Brout papers, discussing how to evade the Goldstone's theorem.

Comment: Ya but the work of Higgs was based on the work of Gilbert and Klein and Lee. You can see the references mentioned in the Higgs 1964 papers.

Comment: @Omkar It was not *based on* the two papers you refer to, it *contradicts* them (say quickly). Please see the edit of the answer, and the document I previoulsy cited.